# Formik React email domain validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Can someone help me to add validation to email field

I have white listed domain field it may have domains like (gmail.com, yopmail.com)
The email field should only contain the domains mentioned in the domain field
How can we do this?

Note:
As we start entering the domains in the field it should start validating the email field domain.

Ex: if the Email field: lock@gmail.com

Domain field:
yopmail.com =>(as we start typing y o p it should validate these characters against email field domain i.e (gmail.com) and if not matching then should show error "domain not matching".
mail.com =>  (as we start typing m a i it should validate these characters against email field domain i.e (gmail.com)  and should show error "domain not matching".
gmail.com => it should validate against email domain if matching then there should not be any error.

```
<div>
                      <label htmlFor="firstName" className="required flex">Email</label>
                        <FormikTextInput
                          name=contactEmail"
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="example.com"
                        />
                      </div>
```

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-1  gap-x-8 pb-3">
                      <div className="mb-2 required flex">
                        White listed email domain address
                      </div>
                      <FieldArray name="EmailDomainlist">
                        {(filedArrayProps) => {
                          let {
                            push,
                            remove,
                            form: {
                              values: { EmailDomainlist },
                            },
                          } = filedArrayProps;
                          return EmailDomainlist.map((email, index) => (
                            <div key={index} className="flex mb-4">
                              <FormikTextInput
                                name={`EmailDomainlist[${index}]`}
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="example.com"
                                list={EmailDomainlist}
                              />
                              <img
                                className="cursor-pointer ml-3"
                                onClick={() => push("")}
                                src={plusIcon}
                                alt="plus icon"
                              />
                              {index > 0 ? (
                                <img
                                  className="cursor-pointer ml-3"
                                  src={deleteIcon}
                                  onClick={() => remove(index)}
                                  alt="delete icon"
                                />
                              ) : null}
                            </div>
                          ));
                        }}
                      </FieldArray>
                    </div>

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FF7W.png
```